# Logging nodejs output with detached screen mode

Tags: node.js, screen, stdout

I have this script which I would like to log output for.

```
for i in {1..20}
do
  sleep 2
  echo "Running Bot $i"
  screen -dm node testbot.js test localhost 4 > $i.txt
done
```

The log files get created but nothing is getting put into them. It works when I run them singularly in the shell with:

`node testbot.js test localhost 4 > test.txt`

but it doesn't work in a detached screen. I experimented with this variation also:

`screen -dm node testbot.js test localhost 4 | tee $i.txt`

but it didn't work either. testbot.js just has some console.log() statements in it.

What can i do to get output into the log files?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. I modified the script and now the output is being logged.

```
for i in {1..20}
do
  sleep 2
  echo "Running Bot $i"
  logfile="$i.txt" 
  export logfile
  screen -mdS bot$i bash -c 'node testbot.js test localhost 4 &> $logfile'  
done
```